# How to compare 2 dictionaries stored sperately in 2 different functions within the script test.py(Python)

Tags: python

In test.py,

```
def module1():
    ....
    ....
    ....
    print dic1

module1()

def module2():
    ....
    ....
    ....
    print dic2

module2()
```

I want to have a function named `module3()` in `test.py` which would compare the 2 dictionaries in the simplest way and display the result `'matched'` if they match else `'not matched'` if they do not match. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just return the dictionaries?

```
def module1():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return dic1

def module2():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return dic2:

def module3():
    d1 = module1()
    d2 = module2()
    if d1 == d2:
        print 'matched'
    else:
        print 'not matched'
```